# Auto height text content under relative (parent) content

Tags: css, css-position

Cant get over this problem. I've designed a small container:

The text content inside is absolute. I'm trying to make the text container height responsive with just css no js...

I'd greatly appreciate any help :)

The small rectangle is..

```
.left-area {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(73, 50, 76);
  width: 144px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-top: 109px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

The description is..

```
.app-desc {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 78%;
      padding: 17px 10px 10px 30px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: medium;
    }
```

here's the right area..

```
.right-area {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(73, 50, 76);
  width: 88%;
  height: 128px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

Every element needs to sorta stay where it is.. for example the ratings too..

```
.app-rating {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -10%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think an absolutely positioned element won't affect the height of its parent container.

Comment: as @zgood pointed out, if a element is absolutely positioned, it won't affect its parent height, much like it wasn't there at all; one way would be to maybe remove the absolute position on the text, so it's container would expand naturally with the content

Comment: or maybe work with a fixed height it the above solution is out of the question

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute;` on the text block container is positioning relative to the parent container but it's then overriding the `display: inline-block` rule, so the child size attributes won't be considered by the parent, because it is effectively acting alone. If the absolute was removed the parent containers fixed height will also block element from growing the containers height.

Try the following:

- remove the absolute rule on the `.app-desc` container
- remove the fixed height on the parent `.right-area` container and add `height: 100%;` to ensure the parent container reacts to the child block element
- Then add a `min-height:` to the `.right-area` so the container doesn't go to short if there isn't enough content in the child

Please see example where I've tried to replicate your scenario: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae920ff5/2/) (I wasn't sure where to position the icons/buttons so they may need some tweaking)

Hope this helps, and if you want to know anymore about positioning absolute to relative parents and how they react with block elements then there's loads of documentation and examples on the [W3 School site - Position Section](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)